# how to put date condition in android after if

Tags: android, date

I made an application and I put DAY_OF_MONTH condition after (if) like this

```
if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 9) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TextActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("key", getResources().getString(R.string.s_monday_txt));
        startActivity(intent1);
        finish();
    } else if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 10) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TextActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("key", getResources().getString(R.string.s_tuesday_txt));
        startActivity(intent2);
        finish();
    }
```

and in another place I put MONTH condition after (if) like this

```
    if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TextActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("key", getResources().getString(R.string.s_september_txt));
        startActivity(intent1);
        finish();
    } else if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.AUGUST) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TextActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("key", getResources().getString(R.string.s_august_txt));
        startActivity(intent2);
        finish();
    }
```

this works fine for me but the problem how can I check the two condition in the same time like this

```
if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER) + (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 9) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TextActivity.class);
        intent1.putExtra("key", getResources().getString(R.string.s_september_txt));
        startActivity(intent1);
        finish();
    } else if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.AUGUST)  + (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 10) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TextActivity.class);
        intent2.putExtra("key", getResources().getString(R.string.s_august_txt));
        startActivity(intent2);
        finish();
    }
```

I tried (+) , (and), (||), (,) all of this don't work
any help ???

Comment: Use && [http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/45.html]

Comment: you mean I put It like this?
if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER) && (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 9) {

Comment: btw the webpage you provide it don't open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, the + sign is an addition. If you want the "and" meaning, use the && sign.

&& - and

|| - or

so if you want to check if both conditions inside your if statement applies then use it like this:

```
if (value == 1 && value2 == 1){
 // do something if value is equal to 1 _AND_ value2 equals to 1
}
```

Comment: you mean I put It like this? if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER) && (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 9) {

Comment: they underline get and this what they give me
The method get(int) in the type Calendar is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)

Comment: You are also not using the brackets properly. 

if (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER &&  cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 9){
 // do something
}

calc.get is a function which will return something that you'll check

Comment: another question can I check the year with day and month in the same condition?

Comment: I strongly recommend to look up a few online docs about Java before doing anything. The syntax, the object oriented thinking is a must have thing if you want to code.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `&&` for **and** and `||` for **or**.

In `cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER) + (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 9`

Change it to this:

```
cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER) && (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 9
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the explanation what `&&`, `||` means. Use the operator as per your requirement

```
if ((cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER) && (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 9)) {
 // it is  september and day of month is 9
}


if ((cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER) || (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == 9)) {
 // either september or 9
}
```

refer the [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/operators-in-java)

Comment: I've got this message 
Syntax error on token "&&", invalid OnlySynchronized
with && red underlined

Comment: the code above has some braces missing, Also `&&`,`||` works on boolean.